# Adding a basic HTML front-end stops JavaScript require from working

Tags: javascript, import

I wrote some JavaScript code that runs in NodeJS and now I am trying to convert it to have a basic HTML front-end where users can input some data into a textarea.

Current I import cryptoJS by using require, like this.

```
const sha256 = require("crypto-js/sha256");

class Block {
  constructor(index, timestamp, data, previousHash = '') {
    this.index = index;
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
    this.data = data;
    this.previousHash = previousHash;
    this.hash = this.calculateHash();
  }

  calculateHash() {
    return sha256(this.index + this.previousHash + this.timestamp + JSON.stringify(this.data)).toString();
  }
}
```

But after adding an HTML front end I get this error; [Require is not defined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eg0m.png)

Is anyone able to explain why adding an HTML front-end would stop this from working?

Comment: The code you put is not the part of your code that has the error!

Comment: require is part of nodejs to load modules.. it's not part of web api and will fail on browser. you are mixing up server side js and client side js... that's not how it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue, I believe that require() is specific to NodeJS.
Now that you have added an HTML front-end you would be launching your code in a browser rather than NodeJS.

Try adding this line to your HTML;

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.1.1/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```

Then change your return to use CryptoJS.SHA256, like this;

```
calculateHash() {
  return CryptoJS.SHA256(this.index + this.previousHash + this.timestamp + JSON.stringify(this.data)).toString();
}
```